# Generate a PDF from a view for emailing

Tags: objective-c, pdf-generation

I have a view with several labels and text views. I am trying to generate a PDF file for that page/view and attach to an email.

First, I tried this approach and it seems either the file is not created or not attached to the email. Here are my codes:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

[self.view drawRect:self.view.bounds];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;



[pdfData writeToFile:file atomically:YES];



[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:file];

[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

And since that didn't work, I tried  a different approach by creating the PDF separately first, then attach it to the email. Then I saw that the PDF file is created at that directory, but it is empty!!!

Here are my revised codes:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *file = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/tempFile.pdf"];

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(file, self.view.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

[self.view drawRect:self.view.bounds];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;



[pdfData writeToFile:file atomically:YES];



[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:file];


[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

- Can you please help me to successfully create a PDF from a view, then attach it to the email?

Answer (score 3):

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.view.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:@"file.pdf"];

[self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
```

Note :
Don't know the draw rect works for views.For me its not working!
No need to write data into a file.you can directly do it while the mail is composed as

```
[mailComposer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"pdf" fileName:@"file.pdf"];
```

try this .The mime type requires only the string pdf.Also include the extension to the file name file.pdf.