# Obj-C View to PDF only renders first page

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiview, pdf-generation

I've got a UIView extension class called UIView+PDFView which takes the current view, splits it into pages, and renders a PDF document. My issue lies in the rendering part; I can successfully 'create' pages for content, however all pages after the first are blank. My end goal is to take the current view, 'scale' the width equal to the page, and paginate the rest of the view within a PDF.

What the issue isn't:

- Attaching the PDF to e-mail
- Sending the PDF to a printer/print simulator
- Only printing one page while actually generating the PDF correctly
- Correctly resizing the view [(SO Question 4919388)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919388/generate-a-pdf-from-a-view-for-emailing)

  - I do this before I send to method. Verified by making frame 10px tall, still prints one (and only one) full page
- Correctly translating the view. Verified by making both a translation and a scale; both correctly changed the view, however neither rendered on more than the first page.

My code is as follows:

```
@interface UIView (PDFView)
-(id)createPDFAndSaveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename andDocumentInfo:(NSDictionary *)documentInfo;
@end

@implementation UIView (PDFView)

-(id)createPDFAndSaveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename andDocumentInfo:(NSDictionary *)documentInfo {
    // http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Auxiliary_Dictionary_Keys

    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    CGSize pageSize = CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, 792);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, documentInfo);
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    NSInteger currentPage = 0;
    BOOL done = NO;

    do {
        CGRect currentPageRect = CGRectMake(0, (pageSize.height*currentPage), pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(currentPageRect, nil);

        // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
        [self.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

        // If we're at the end of the view, exit the loop.
        if ((pageSize.height*currentPage) > self.bounds.size.height) {
            done = YES;
        } else {
            currentPage++;
        }
    } while (!done);

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    if (aFilename == nil) {
        return pdfData;
    } else {
        // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
        NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

        NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

        // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
        [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think your problem lies

```
CGRect currentPageRect = CGRectMake(0, (pageSize.height*currentPage), pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
```

instead of that try using either of the below statements

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0), nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
```

everytime you wish to add a new page to the context use the above statements and you would be able to add pages to the context.

if you wish to use the default size of the page i.e. 612 X 792 you can directly use `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();`

for custom page size you can use `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 612.0, 792.0), nil);`

I think that should solve your problem.

Comment: I used your code and added the transform below before the renderInContext: method and got the result I'm looking for, thanks!
`CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0, -(pageSize.height*currentPage));`

Comment: Thanks @ScottBonAmi this is was exactly my problem!